# Matching any character through Thompson's algorithm

Tags: c, regex, algorithm

I am using Thompson's algorithm to build an NFA from a postfix regex string. I need to be able to accept any ASCII character. However, the only solution I can think of is creating a large list of union statements for each character:
`...|a|b|c|d|e|f|...|0|1|2|3|4|...|;|:|'|/|[|]|...`

Is there a simpler approach? I believe could deviate from Thompson's algorithm and just make 128 (one for each ASCII character) connections to the next state. but would complicate my setup.
What is the best solution here?

Comment: Why not get the its ASCII code and check of it's in range 128?

Comment: Model the transition using a bitmap?  If bit *n* is set in the bitmap, then you are allowed to take the transition if the input has character code *n.*  Though this makes it a bit of a hassle to move to bigger character sets -- you'd need millions of bits for each transition to support Unicode.

Comment: Interesting idea, I'm not looking to use Unicode anyways. I will look into it, thank you.

Comment: Is it possible to make one connection, which specifies that as long as the current character matches any of the character in the connection, it can follows the connection?

Comment: I like that idea, I could keep it simple by using a range instead. All I would need to do is give each connection another `int` for an optional min/max.